# Nested h3 in scss not working

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to change the margins of an h3 tag using scss in Angular.  The scss is working but when I nest h3 inside a div tag it does not work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

SCSS

```
// Does not work
.subTitle {
    h3 {
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
}

// Works
h3 {
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let post of allPosts" class="col-md-12 blogPost">
        <div id="title"><h1>{{post.title}}</h1></div>
        <div id="subTitle"><h3>{{post.subTitle}}</h3></div>
        <div id="blogContent"><p>{{post.content}}</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

Comment: Use the dev toolbar to check how exactly the output html dom looks like (check how angular generated the DOM for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your markup sets the `id`, and you CSS targets a class using the `.` syntax. Use `#subTitle` in CSS, or change the markup to use `class=subTitle`.

You should use a class because you're inside the `*ngFor`, and multiple elements should not have the same ID.

Comment: ahh, durr. I replaced id with class and problem is solved. Thanks.